# how to create a decorator that sends an argument to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper

I'm trying to create a decorator that goes through a bunch of files and applies the function to the text. Problem is that the wrapped function needs to receive a text and the returned wrapped function does not.

The function works fine if I define it receiving only parameters

```
import os
def manipulate( folder, func, *args, **kwargs ):
    for file_name in os.listdir( folder ):
        with open( file_name , 'r' ) as f:
            text = ''.join(f.readlines())

        func( text, *args, **kwargs )

        with open( file_name , 'w' ) as f:
            f.write(text)
```

but I wish I could transform this into a decorator

```
import os, functools

def manip( folder ):

    def decorator( func ):

        @functools.wraps( func )
        def wrapper( *args, **kwargs ):
            for file_name in os.listdir( folder ):
                with open( file_name , 'r' ) as f:
                    text = ''.join(f.readlines())

                func( text, *args, **kwargs )

                with open( file_name , 'w' ) as f:
                    f.write(text)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

now if I have a function:

```
def add_after( text, after='to be added' ):
    return text + after

manipulate('./MyFolder/', add_after)
```

the manipulate function works fine.

but using the manip decorator like:

```
@manip('./MyFolder/')
def add_after( text, after='to be added' ):
    return text + after

manip()
```

gives me the error:

```
Type Error: add_after() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

I can't figure out what's wrong or if I just shouldn't be trying to do it like this. The idea is to be able to create util functions to help me edit a bunch of text/json files when needed and use this decorator to make a call on the decorated function already apply itself to all the text files on that folder.

Comment: Don't you need to add a parameter to your `manip` function for the `func` argument?

Comment: what do you mean? I'd like an example. My current problem is that the function I'm wrapping needs to receive text as an arguments, but after it's wrapped it does not need anymore, because the text argument is going to be fed by the wrapper. With the decorator I get the problem that python still asks for an argument text on the wrapped function.

Comment: `def manip(func, folder):` is what I mean